# Python locks on asyncio socket operations

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, python-asyncio

I tried to make a program that connects two sockets, by writing the data read on one socket to the other and vice versa.

```
import socket as sock
import asyncio

BUFF_SIZE = 4096


async def create_relay(s, port, loop):
    while True:
        s1, _ = await loop.sock_accept(s)  # while awaiting sock_accept no other task is run
        s2 = sock.socket(sock.AF_INET, sock.SOCK_STREAM)
        await loop.sock_connect(s2, ('localhost', port))
        loop.create_task(relay(s1, s2, loop))
        loop.create_task(relay(s2, s1, loop))
        # await asyncio.sleep(1000)        # while awaiting sleep the relay tasks are run

async def relay(s1, s2, loop):
    data = await loop.sock_recv(s1, BUFF_SIZE)
    while data:
        await loop.sock_sendall(s2, data)
        data = await loop.sock_recv(s1, BUFF_SIZE)


def main():
    s = sock.socket(sock.AF_INET, sock.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.bind(('localhost', 9999))
    s.listen()
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(create_relay(s, 9990, loop))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

While this program successfully sets up the sockets, I can't actually transfer any messages. Debugging the code has shown that the program gets stuck at `s1, _ = await loop.sock_accept(s)` and doesn't execute any of the other asynchronous code while `await`ing another connection. If however I add another `await`, like `await asyncio.sleep(1000)` at the end of the `create_relay` loop the relay works at least partially and I can forward the messages in one direction.

Can somebody explain, why these lock-ups happen and how to avoid them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can somebody explain, why these lock-ups happen and how to avoid them?

The code doesn't make the sockets non-blocking. You need to add:

```
s.setblocking(False)
```

in *every* place where you create or obtain a new socket.

Also, `sock_connect`, `sock_accept`, `sock_recv`, and `sock_sendall` are considered low-level APIs that are not meant to be directly used by application code. Instead, your code should use the [stream APIs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-stream.html), which provide features such as buffering, and of course automatically create non-blocking sockets.